# How to sniff all HTTP packets on a wifi network?

Tags: http, wifi, packet-capture, packet-sniffer

I need to sniff all HTTP packets that pass through my wifi network (in particular HTTP requests by my smartphone). I've tried with wireshark, but I can sniff only packets to and from my pc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Anyway this may help you: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do it is to tap the wireless network where the access point connects to the wired network.

You could do this with a dedicated network tap device, or a managed switch with a SPAN port configured, then you'll be able to sniff the traffic traversing the network.

Answer (score 0):

You must put your NIC into [Promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode). This might or might not be supported by your WiFi adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Since your wlan interface is dropping packets at MAC level when not being the destination (for example packets between your phone and AP) you must put you wlan interface in monitor mode or you can do arp spoofing with phone <---> AP first and then you will see traffic of your phone with wireshark.